# Tensorflow did not save the required models

Tags: tensorflow

I ask tensorflow to save models every 100 iterations in every epoch, the following is my code. But after 900 iterations, only trained models for the 500th, 600th, 700th, 800th, 900th iterations were saved.

```
with tf.Session(config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement = True)) as sess:

    sess.run(init_op)

    for i in range(args.num_epochs):
        start_time = time.time()
        k = 0
        acc_train = 0
        # initialize the iterator to train_dataset
        sess.run(train_init_op)
        while True:
            try:
                accu, l, _ = sess.run([accuracy, loss, optimizer], feed_dict = {training: True})
                k += 1
                acc_train += accu
                if k % 100 == 0:
                    print('Epoch: {}, step: {}, training loss: {:.3f}, training accuracy: {:.2f}%'.format(i, k, l, accu * 100))
                    saver.save(sess, args.saved_model_path, global_step = (i+1) * k)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break
```

The following is the training accuracies:

Epoch: 0, step: 100, training loss: 0.669, training accuracy: 59.38%

Epoch: 0, step: 200, training loss: 0.806, training accuracy: 54.69%

Epoch: 0, step: 300, training loss: 0.781, training accuracy: 57.81%

Epoch: 0, step: 400, training loss: 0.725, training accuracy: 64.06%

Epoch: 0, step: 500, training loss: 0.347, training accuracy: 89.06%

Epoch: 0, step: 600, training loss: 0.193, training accuracy: 89.06%

Epoch: 0, step: 700, training loss: 0.003, training accuracy: 100.00%

Epoch: 0, step: 800, training loss: 0.190, training accuracy: 98.44%

Epoch: 0, step: 900, training loss: 0.009, training accuracy: 100.00%

My question is why tensorflow did not saved models for the 100th, 200th, 300th, 400th iterations? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow saver seems to overwrite existing saved variable files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386016/tensorflow-saver-seems-to-overwrite-existing-saved-variable-files)

Answer (score 2):

It did, but I'm guessing the [`Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#__init__) instance you created had the default `max_keep` value of 5, so it overwrote them as the last 5 were created. To keep 10, change your saver creation line to

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_keep=10)
```

You might also want to play with the `keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours` argument if you don't want to save -every- one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just checked https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver. It by default just keep 5 checkpoints. max_to_keep=5