# Restoring Tensorflow model from a previous checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am tuning my model for 200 episodes by training it 2 times each for 100 episodes. The first run for 100 eps is finished and right now 2nd run is going on. My problem is I want to restore the model after it finished the first run that is from the 100th episode. And now that I have already started the 2nd run, it has overwritten the checkpoint files.

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386016/tensorflow-saver-seems-to-overwrite-existing-saved-variable-files) which says tensorflow keeps last 5 models. How can I retrieve the model parameters from the previous checkpoint which was created after the first run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow saves the best 5 models in a single run, you have started another new run, i am afraid your models are lost, you will have to retrain them, rule of thumb always keep the naming of your models dynamic so they aren't replaced, for example:

```
model_name = 'Model_{:d}'.format(episode_number) + '.ckpt'
```

Comment: thank you for the tip ! can you also let me know how could i retrieve , say , the 3rd model. How do i specify it in `saver.restore` ?

Comment: You may do this by doing `restore_saver = tf.train.Saver()
restore_saver.restore(sess,model_name)` where model name can be `Model_3.ckpt` thus restoring the 3rd model